# Maps - Safest routes

Tags: api, google-maps, maps, dijkstra

As a student I've learned a lot of things about graphs and algorithms running there. I know that we can use algorithms to calculate the minimum path based on distance. Also, we can use graphs with weighs, like restrictions.

In the real world, everybody knows about Google Maps, that show us the best routes based on distance, traffic, cost. I suppose those factors, like cost and traffic are weights in the graph no?

Well, I want to create a service/app, that makes use of the registered number of accidents per path, to calculate the safest path. In reality I think this is a restriction/weight, but my problem is : What is the API/service which allows me to add this restriction to the maps? I've searched for the Google Maps API, but it just allows users for search paths based on their restrictions (distance/traffic/travel cost) and I think it won't allows me to introduce my safe factor.

If you know the solution please tell me, it would be awesome !

Comment: Somewhat related (just saw it on hackernews a minute ago): http://streetscore.media.mit.edu/about.html - they used an algorithm to calculate _perceived safety_ of streets based on street view images. It's not about real crime rate or accidents though. If all you need is another weight for your graph you could give it a try, you can download their dataset.

Comment: It looks amazing and Difficult ! In my case, I have the information about number of accidents. I just don't know how to integrate them in the map !

Comment: *What is the API/service which allows me to add this restriction to the maps* **...why do you assume that there is such a ressource?**

Comment: Well, it is just positive supposition :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be easily doable with GraphHopper which uses OpenStreetMap data. Download the repository - see this [video intro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBVe_E5j0TM). Then change the weighting to your custom one. Read [here](https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/core/weighting.md) where a bit custom Java code will be necessary. (Note: I'm the author)

Answer (score 5):

I don't know of any API that lets you add arbitrary weights to Google Maps searches. It seems you can't download their map either.

You could load the maps data from a service like OpenStreetMaps, and create your own graph of it. Then you add new weighting based on your traffic safety data to the graph and run your own search algorithm of choice to calculate safe routes.

You could then reintegrate your results back into Google Maps, by drawing an svg [overlay on the map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays?hl=en) showing your route.

Comment: Humm it seems clear. But is it possible? (Convert Google Maps data to a graph + add weights to that graph + apply algorithms on that) ?

Comment: @CarlosPiedade I think I may have mixed it up with some other maps service.. I've seen projects displaying custom routes on gmaps but the data for the graph could have been from other services. It seems google doesn't provide any street data. You could try www.openstreetmap.org instead, they definitely let you download their data.

Comment: It's true, I saw it at 5m ago. I've downloaded a part of the map and the format file is an .osm. Is it possible to convert it on a graph? How?

Comment: @CarlosPiedade Sorry I never used osm format so I don't know. I think it is possible though. It seems there are quite a lot open source libraries and apps that you could use or look how they do it. See http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing

Comment: Thanks @Kepep ! It won't be easy, that's a fact :)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of thinking about Google Maps, use the open data from OpenStreetMap.
I suggest looking in building your routing application via an existing router and weighing each way as you like.
OSRM (https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/wiki) uses profiles to build the routing graph, and different instances have built custom profiles or dealt with merging other information in the routing graph.
Only an example, this sample code queries a PostGIS database during graph building (https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/blob/992458ae4ba1ea2bcf6234bee090297baef33600/profiles/examples/postgis.lua)